# Is a /dev/loop preferred for mounting file-as-filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, mount, loopback, fuse

I have been hacking around with files as filesystems, for things like encrypted volumes and the like. [This tutorial](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/2096-use-a-file-as-a-linux-block-device) uses `losetup` and a `/dev/loopX` device to facilitate the mount process. However, [another tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-a-file-based-filesystem-using-dd-command-on-linux) does not, they just `mount file.fs /mnt/tmp`.

Is the /dev/loop approach best practice? I could not get the first example of the first tutorial (using `losetup`) to work as-is, though `mount -o /dev/loopX` worked for me. The second tutorial worked fine just as well, though it looks like based on `df` it automagically created a `/dev/loopX`...soo is this approach even any different?

This question is similar, but not quite, it asks about journalling on top of loopback. https://superuser.com/a/266177/617695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is this approach even any different?

No. Modern `mount` is smart enough to automate the process, so you don't need to invoke `losetup` by hand. The following fragment of [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#THE_LOOP_DEVICE) is relevant [emphasis mine]:

> THE LOOP DEVICE
>
> One further possible type is a mount via the loop device. For example, the command
>
> ```
> mount /tmp/disk.img /mnt -t vfat -o loop=/dev/loop3
> ```
>
> will set up the loop device `/dev/loop3` to correspond to the file `/tmp/disk.img`, and then mount this device on `/mnt`.
>
> If no explicit loop device is mentioned (but just an option `-o loop` is given), then `mount` will try to find some unused loop device and use that, for example
>
> ```
> mount /tmp/disk.img /mnt -o loop
> ```
>
> **The `mount` command automatically creates a loop device from a regular file** if a filesystem type is not specified or the filesystem is known for `libblkid`, for example:
>
> ```
> mount /tmp/disk.img /mnt
>
> mount -t ext4 /tmp/disk.img /mnt
> ```
>
> This type of mount knows about three options, namely `loop`, `offset` and `sizelimit`, that are **really options to `losetup(8)`**. (These options can be used in addition to those specific to the filesystem type.)
>
> Since Linux 2.6.25 **auto-destruction of loop devices is supported**, meaning that any loop device allocated by `mount` will be freed by `umount` independently of `/etc/mtab`.
>
> You can also free a loop device by hand, using `losetup -d` or `umount -d`.
>
> Since `util-linux` v2.29 mount command re-uses the loop device rather than initialize a new device if the same backing file is already used for some loop device with the same `offset` and `sizelimit`. This is necessary to avoid a filesystem corruption.

Comment: By "modern mount" are we talking anything since at least, say, Debian 8 / ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @DeusXMachina More like since Debian 1.1 (1996), if [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466938/108618#comment851381_466940) is right. Ubuntu started few years later.